# Type inference from Enum

Tags: typescript, generics

I'd like to infer a property type from an `enum` like so:

```
enum Foo {
  One, Two
}

type Bar = {...}
type BarOne = Bar & {...}
type BarTwo = Bar & {...}

export type MyType<T extends Foo> = {
  data: // How do I set this type to be BarOne if Foo.One, BarTwo if Foo.Two, etc.?
}
```

Totally open to hearing a different approach if this is not ideal.

Comment: So you want to associate an enum value to a type ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional typing if the number of your enum values are limited :

```
enum Foo {
  One, Two
}

type Bar = { foo: string }
type BarOne = Bar & { bar: string }
type BarTwo = Bar & { baz: string }

export type MyType<T extends Foo> = {
  data: T extends Foo.One ? BarOne : T extends Foo.Two ? BarTwo : never 
}

type FooOne = MyType<Foo.One> // { data: BarOne }

type FooTwo = MyType<Foo.Two> // { data: BarTwo }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAYg9nKBvAUFKB5EwA0UAqA7nCgL4ooAuAngA7BQBCAhgE5QC8yUAZggFxQAzpVYBLEAHMo5GvSZssDLi3YAybgCM2gkeKkyqdBqqKIVbKBqRRtAL12iJ08imAAPWnFaUochgCy1PjGADz4UB6UoAAmQrAIAHycyGhQMcyUzIIRUbHx8HAAdEpQAPwKrKU5ke7RIHEJxWbllS2C2ABuwOxkFP5NpVxBIfShhSXYiSgA9DPoUAB6Zf3GTS3DwWETZtNzC8tAA)

Answer (score 1):

Other possibility: A Map to associate an enum value to a type !

```
enum Foo {
  One, Two
}

type Bar = { foo: string }
type BarOne = Bar & { bar: string }
type BarTwo = Bar & { baz: string }

type FooMap = {
  [Foo.One]: BarOne
  [Foo.Two]: BarTwo
}

type FooOne = FooMap[Foo.One]  // { data: BarOne }
type FooTwo = FooMap[Foo.Two]  // { data: BarTwo }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAYg9nKBvAUFKB5EwA0UAqA7nCgL4ooAuAngA7BQBCAhgE5QC8yUAZggFxQAzpVYBLEAHMo5GvSZssDLi3YAybgCM2gkeKkyqdBqqKIVbKBqRRtAL12iJ08kfnw4AWWa1OyNFAA2h4AdEoAuoKqSgHBCCFmkQqsZmQUcgweSn4e3rRxcGHY4W6ZCGY5CHkFCcThQA)